# Postman can not capture Telegram API calls

Tags: postman, reverse-engineering

I have installed OpenSSL and Postman certificate file on both iPad and Android phone. Postman is properly capturing http and https requests from various apps (example - Microsoft Teams, Gmail), but it doesn't capture API calls when I open Telegram and send someone a message or perform other operation such as adding profile picture.

What can be possible reason for this to happen? Any insight is appreciated, thank you.